# How to install Bouncy Castle on UWP using Nuget

Tags: xamarin, nuget, uwp, bouncycastle

I'm developing a program using xamarin forms and UWP. I've installed Bouncy Castle on my PCL project and I'm able to use some elements like Sha1Digest.

I would like to use the SecureRandom object from Boucy Castle too, but when using

> SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

I'm getting some `System.TypeInitializationException`.

After some test I've found that Bouncy Castle wasn't installed on my UWP project so I went to install this packages but i can't.

I'm always getting some `Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'App1'.` errors. I also get `BouncyCastle 1.8.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).`

Do you have any idea to use this package ?

Comment: found any solution for installing BouncyCastle on UWP?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install it using this package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.BouncyCastle-Signed/

Comment: That is an unofficial library. Please use Portable.BouncyCastle. I am the maintainer of the portable fork. If you're still hitting issues, please file something in the repo here: https://github.com/onovotny/bc-csharp